# How to handle empty field names in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to log users' input to my RESTful API for debugging purpose but whenever there's an empty field in the JSON payload, an error is generated and the log is discarded.

For instance,

```
{
  "extra": {
    "request": {
      "body": {
        "": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...will result in

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "field name cannot be an empty string"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

It seems to be caused by https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/45e7e24736eeb4a157ac89bd16a374dbf917ae26/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/mapper/DocumentParser.java#L191.

It's a bit tricky since it happens in the parsing phase... Is there any workaround to remove/rename such fields so that it can enable ES to digest these logs?